# Windows 7 batch file Copy all files from a folder structure to one folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I've a folder structure like

```
    Folder0
    -f1
       -f11
             file1.txt
             file2.txt
        -f12
            file3.txt
    -f2
        -f21
            file4.txt
            file5.txt
               -f13
                   file6.txt
                   file7.txt

Folder1
 -f4
     -f41
        file1.txt
        file2.txt
     -f42
        file3.txt
 -f5
     -f51
        file4.txt
        file5.txt
            -f53
                file6.txt
                file7.txt
etc...
```

and I want a merged folder like

```
Folder0
 file1.txt
 file2.txt
 file3.txt
 file4.txt
 file5.txt
 file6.txt
 file7.txt

Folder1
 file1.txt
 file2.txt
 file3.txt
 file4.txt
 file5.txt
 file6.txt
 file7.txt
```

can anyone please help me to create a batch file for the same.. I've about 200 folders like this..

please help

Comment: In your question, you realize that you are creating duplicate names in the same flatten folder, which is not allowed?  You are going to need to indicate in your question how you expect duplicate file names in subdirectories to be resolved.

Comment: ok, if I can manage duplicate names.. can then it be possible..?

Comment: Google "windows flatten a folder directory structure" ... all sorts of examples out there